# Apache CLI CommandLine: Remove an option that was parsed

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

## Description

I have a CommandLine object that parses Options that I pass to it. Below I have passed 2 options to the commandline.

```
String[] userInputs = {"-option1","value1","option2","value2"};
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("option1"));
    options.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("option2"));
    CommandLine commandLine = null;
    try {
        commandLine = new BasicParser().parse(options,userInputs);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## Issue

I have a requirement where I want to run some unit tests by removing one or more options (say, option2) from commandline. I have tried this approach-

```
options.getOptions().remove(options.getOption("option2"));
```

But this gives me a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
**I am looking for a clean approach to remove any option of my choice.**

## Version

Maven dependency is-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Options.getOptions()` returns a `unmodifiableCollection` on purpose to not allow such modifications.

So you will need to replace the whole `Options` object with one that is used for testing.

E.g. via a test-only setter into your commandline-handling which replaces the options with a reduced set of options. Probably by reading the options from the original set and adding all except the one that you want to filter, e.g. something like

```
Options testOptions = new Options();
for(Option option : options.getOptions) {
    if(!option.getArg().equals(...)) {
        testOptions.addOption(testOptions);
    }
}
```